# Merging / combining columns is not working at all

Tags: r, merge

I cant for the life of me figure out a way of getting this working without changing the class of the columns or getting a random level that isn't even in the original columns!

I have data that looks like this:

```
data <- structure(list(WHY = structure(1:4, .Label = c("WHY1", "WHY2", 
"WHY3", "WHY4"), class = "factor"), HELP1 = structure(c(3L, NA, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "D/A"), class = "factor"), HELP2 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

What I want to do:
If HELP 2 IS NOT NA & IF HELP1 is D/A then merge columns WITHOUT changing class.

Here is what I tried:

```
data$HELP3 <-
  ifelse(
    !is.na(data$HELP2) &
      data$HELP1 == "D/A",
        data$HELP1, data$HELP2)
```

Result:

```
     data
   WHY HELP1 HELP2 HELP3
1 WHY1   D/A    NA    NA
2 WHY2  <NA>     2    NA
3 WHY3     1    NA    NA
4 WHY4     2    NA    NA
>
```

I would be so very very very grateful for any help with this. I have been on stack overflow for 5 hours now and no closer to making this work :( I am not that hot with dyplr so a base r or anything else would be wonderful!

Comment: For this example your expected output would be `HELP3` column same as `HELP1` ?

Comment: Hi @RonakShah yes it is, ideally I would just have HELP 1 where if it is NA then I would pull the value from HELP 2 if there is one. I just updated as I had the last bit of the if else statement back to front here.

Comment: If you want to do If value is present in Help 1 take it else take value from Help2 you can use `dplyr::coalesce(data$HELP1, data$HELP2)` but this does not take into consideration `data$HELP1 == "D/A"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `HELP2` and `HELP1` have different class and `ifelse` also has issues to return vector of `factor` class. You could however, do this without `ifelse` and without changing the classes of columns.

```
data$HELP3 <- data$HELP1
inds <- (!is.na(data$HELP2)) & data$HELP1 == "D/A"
data$HELP3[inds] <- data$HELP2[inds]
```

Comment: You are a genius! I wish I posted for help hours ago. Thanks so much I cant tell how grateful I am.